# Why is Perl HTTP::Response not decoding this apostrophe?

Tags: perl, request, decode, lwp, lwp-useragent

I'm using

```
my $ua = new LWP::UserAgent;
$ua->agent("Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Intel Mac OS X 10.6; rv:7.0.1) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/7.0.1 ");
my $url = "http://somedomain.com/page/";
my $req = new HTTP::Request 'GET' => $url;
$req->header('Accept' => 'text/html');
my $response = $ua->request($req);
my $html = $response->decoded_content;
```

to get a web page. On this page, `Abobo's Big Adventure` appears. In `$request->content` and `$request->decoded_content`, this is shown as `Abobo&#39;s Big Adventure`.

Is there something I can do to make this decode correctly?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Why, that is completely valid HTML! However, you can decode the Entities using [`HTML::Entities`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Entities) from CPAN.

```
use HTML::Entities;

...;
my $html = $response->decoded_content;
my $decoded_string = decode_entities($html);
```

The docs for [`HTTP::Response::decoded_content`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTTP::Response) state that the `Content-encoding` and charsets are reversed, not HTML entities (which are a HTML/XML language feature, not really an encoding).

#### Edit:

However, as ikegami pointed out, decoding the entities immediately could render the HTML unparsable. Therefore, it might be best to parse the HTML first (e.g. using [`HTML::Tree`](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::TreeBuilder)), and then only decoding the text nodes when needed.

```
use HTML::TreeBuilder;

my $url = ...;
my $tree = HTML::TreeBuilder->new_from_url($url);    # invokes LWP automatically
my $decoded_text = decode_entities($tree->as_text);  # dumps the tree as flat text, then decodes.
```

Comment: That doesn't produce HTML as your variable name implies. Take `<p>&lt;i&gt;/foo&lt;i&gt;</p>` for example.

Comment: Did you mean `decode_entities` instead of `deparse_entities`? Other than that, the tree did what I needed and also cleaned up my code nicely. The only thing is that I had to get the HTML with LWP separately and use `HTML::TreeBuilder->from_content($html)` because I didn't see a way to set the UserAgent string. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing there probably is an ampersand there before the hash mark. Making it the HTML entity expressed `&#39;` These aren't that hard to change. You can do something like this:

```
my $content =  $response->decoded_content;
$content    
    =~ s{(&#(\d{2,3});)}{
           $2 < 128 ? ord( $2 ) : $1
        }gem
    ;
```

The range check pretty much assures you you're dealing with ASCII. If you want to get more complex, you could also put together a hash of values, and change it like so:

```
my %entity_lookup
    = ( 150 => '-'
      , 151 => '--' # m-dash
      , 160 => ' '
      ... 
    );
...
$content
    =~ s{(&#(\d+);)}{ 
           $2 < 128 ? ord( $2 ) : $entity_lookup{ $2 } // $1
        }gem
    ;
```

But that would be up to you.

Comment: The correct way to do this is to use [HTML::Entities](https://metacpan.org/module/HTML::Entities) or a similar well-tested module.

Comment: I agree that a well-tested module would be the better approach, but I may not have the permissions I need to install additional modules from CPAN. So I'm happy to know there's a fallback. Thanks